# Using Sharepoint in a Corporate environment - Archiving and Workflows

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, external, archive

I was recently put in charge of being "SharePoint Administrator" for my department.  I am being tasked with the following:

1. Create a user friendly interface for end users (Done)
2. Create an auto-archive process for aged documents.  (ISSUE)
3. Create an interactive workflow for certain reports requiring feedback from end user. (ISSUE)

SO - I am not new to SharePoint, but definitely new to the coding and back end admin component.  I have searched to the ends of the internet but cannot find a step - by - step that doesn't require central admin access (I don't have it, and don't know how to obtain it).

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to set up auto-archive on SharePoint to archive to an external database such as LiveLink without having Central Admin Access?  If so - please advise on steps to do so.
2. If NOT - Is there an alternative and can I set up auto archive to another list within the main SharePoint (I have found tutorials for this but can't seem to find any with step by step instructions so someone without advanced knowledge could go through the process).
3. Workflows - Am I able to upload data to the sharepoint and have a workflow that would send a notification externally (via outlook) to an enduser indicating action required on the data?  The end user would then have to log in to the SharePoint, review the data and take whatever action is required (let's use checking a checkbox as an example of action required).  From there - a notification would go to - say - a senior manager to then go in and access the data and check another box for their approval.  From that point an email notification would go out that the workflow and item is completed and no further action is required.

I apologize for such a long set of questions, I just really want to understand this and feel like I am so close but just need a little more insight.  If you can only answer part of this that's fine too!

Thanks so much to everyone!
Shannon

Comment: You may be better off to ask that question here [SharePoint StackExchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Work with your corporate IT department to find out who **does** have access to Central Admin. Work with them to determine what level of customization you can perform, and what level of support they're willing to offer if your requirements necessitate their direct involvement.